# iPhone build lite and full versions - adMob problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild, admob

I'm traing to build a lite version for my app the way it is described in this post:
[How do I manage building a Lite vs Paid version of an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app)

After creating the two targets the full version can be built the lite version stops building with this error at the 'linking' stage:
"library not found for -lAdMobDevice
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0 failed with exit code 1"

I'm trying to use AdMob for the lite version. Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked that the AdMob library is marked as belonging to both the Lite and Full versions?

(click on library, get info, look on "targets" tab)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Problem solved. I've just removed the admob library and added it again to both targets without checking the 'copy if needed' checkbox.  Do you think the problem had to do with the 'copy if needed' option or just wasn't added to both targets?

Comment: the "copy if needed" I think just controls whether the thing that's added to your project is a copy of the file in your project directory or a reference to the file in its original location.  For something like a library that you're not going to change, it doesn't matter, but if it were a source code file that you might edit, you'd probably want to make a local copy.

Your build problem sounds like the library wasn't a member of the "Lite" target.

Comment: I just had the same problem, and it went away simply by unchecking the ladmob lib and rechecking it.  Rebuilds did not work.  Didn't do anything with "copy if needed."  Seems very buggy.