# Making multiple versions of an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I made an iPhone application, and now I would like to make multiple more versions of the same application with very slightly different functionality.

I was wondering if anyone knew what the best way was to go about duplicating a project with as little decoupling (I think that's the right term) as possible.

Maybe someone out there who has made a LITE version of their iPhone application?  How they went about doing it and what lessons they learned from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoot, I'm sorry.  Didn't find this when I was searching earlier, but looks like a lot of what I am looking for has already been answered here: [How do I manage building a Lite vs Paid version of an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

One low budget, low overhead approach that I've used that will keep things simple is as follows:

```
/******************************************
* Set to 'FREE_APP' or 'PAID_APP' 
******************************************/
#define PAID_APP
```

Within your application, you then write code simimar to the following:

```
#ifdef PAID_APP
  @interface myViewController : UITableViewController 
#else
  @interface myViewController : UITableViewController <CustomTableAppDelegate> 
#endif
```

This is by no means the best all around approach as you still have update the info.plist file to set the executable name and bundle identifier. However, in a pinch, it works well to maintain one code base/project.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's another link](http://www.codza.com/free-iphone-app-version-from-the-same-xcode-project)

I've used this approach and it works pretty well.