# How to set base language other than English in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, localization

I am implementing an app which is going to have `localization`.

But in this case I need to set `base language` as `Portuguese` and not `English`

While implementation my app is going to be in `English` and after that when i change settings to language `Portuguese` it will show in that language,
but

User is going to change the language `from app itself` and should be able to `switch the language`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943659/setting-default-language-for-iphone-app-on-first-run, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196209/setting-language-on-iphone-application, and other SO questions.

Answer (score 3):

In plist file set "Localization native development region " set "German".
u want to set German.
Must have German Localize string file.

Comment: A simple answer that actually answers what is asked for.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "set the base language"?

The app will launch in whatever language the user has his device set to use. If I set the language on my phone to English the app will launch in English. If I set the language of my device to Portuguese the app will launch in Portuguese. If you don't want it to be able to launch in English, don't add localization support for English.

**Edit**

I see what your intention is now. Yes, you can use the "AppleLanguages" preference, like so:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"pr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`

This will make English the primary language of your app, and if an English translation is not available for a string then it will check the next language in the array for a translation.

Comment: user's device has Portuguese initially so it will show all in that language but after that from the app itself it should switch the language and should show everything in English. So is it possible to do?

Comment: If you want to do it within the app itself then you need to create your own system for localization instead of relying on Apple's. I think doing this would be looked down upon. The whole point of localization is that the user can choose which language to view the app in... if I had my device set to Portuguese and opened your app and it displayed in English I wouldn't be happy.

Comment: somewhere I have found this,can this solve the issue?   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
     [defaults synchronize];

Comment: putting this on button click wont change the language right? We need to put this in main.m file for the first time it will take language other than selected in iphone's settings and next time when app opened it will show language selected in iphone