# How do I maintain multiple iOS apps out of a single repository?

Tags: iphone, ios, git, xcode4

I've been digging around stack overflow for a solution to maintaining multiple iOS applications out of a single repository, but have only found things that address lite vs paid versions (such as: [Efficiently build two versions of an Iphone app from a single Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414420/efficiently-build-two-versions-of-an-iphone-app-from-a-single-xcode-project) and [How do I manage building a Lite vs Paid version of an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app)).

What I've been trying to find is a way to create an application that basically has different themes.  They would function almost identically, but would have different names/images/colors and would pull from different web service URLs (but would receive the same response format, just different data).

I currently use git for my source management and am looking to leverage newsstand for this application.

Does anyone have any experience with this or could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single XCode project can have multiple Targets, each Target with its own Build settings, source file selection, and C preprocessor defines.  Between including different source files and using different defines, one can have almost any combination of paid/lite versions, apps with customized themes, or even multiple completely different iOS apps inside one project.  Then just check the whole project directory into one repository.