# iPhone Multiple Targets Bundle ID for LITE and Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, push

I'm slightly confused about my bundle ID and how I configure my new LITE version of my app.

I have created a LITE target as per these instructions: [How do I manage building a Lite vs Paid version of an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app/549570#549570)

All fine, however I need a new bundle ID to submit it to Apple... So, my full version has an App ID of:

123346.com.blah.appName

Because I need it for push notification certificates... However if I create a new ID will my LITE version stop working with the push certifications? Slightly confused how I proceed... Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with push notifications, so take my advice with a bit of care.

However, your Lite version is a completely new app (for Apple), from my understanding. You're just conveniently sharing pieces of code from the full project.

Being like that, you should proceed just like you did for your full version. You have to register a new bundle ID and then register that new bundle ID with the push notifications server.

Like I said, it's just like creating a new app from the ground up. You're just sharing some code.

Comment: My problem is I think the Bundle ID is tied to the push notification certificates... ?

Comment: You probably have to create a new push notification certificate. You'll have to handle each of those separately.