# Lite Version and Full Version app are same or different

Tags: ios, app-store

i have decided to post my app for lite and full version, that **lite version will have advertisements, But full version dont have any ads.**

my question is i **have to post two applications or may i use single app for this?**.

how can differentiate this?.

Comment: `Create multiple targets.`

Comment: so, i want to post the app two times in app store?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "post" a single app in the app store to cover both a lite version and a full version.  Essentially the app initially works as the lite version.  Using an in-app upgrade, you enable or disable features to give the full version experience (e.g., turn off ads).

There are some drawbacks to this approach, such as the launch icon, splash screen, app name displayed below the launch icon cannot be changed, so you can't initially show the app name as 'iApp Lite' and then change it to just 'iApp'.

In my case, I have published both a full and lite version of the same app.  The lite version has an in-app purchase capability to upgrade to a full version.  In the lite version, I handled the 'lite' labeling by showing the word 'Lite' in a couple of places in the app - but only after the splash screen.  Once upgraded to the full version capabilities, these labels are no longer shown, and full version features are enabled.

Comment: In my case, I wish to deliver complete feature to the user for free for a limited period say 1 month. 

After one month app will prompt the user to pay us. If he doesn't pay, app will give him only the basic feature and stop advanced features. 

Is this possible, if we use Non-Renewing Subscription ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create two separated targets, one for full version and one for free version. Then you will have to publish two apps. Or you can use In App Purchase to disable ads. With In App Purchase you will publish only one app. I would recommend using IAP because your users will not need to download the same app twice to get the full version.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple targets.

You can vary build configurations by right-clicking on a target and selecting Get Info. 
From there, you can do things like change which Info.plist file it's looking at (to do things like add "Lite" to the name and change the icon/load images) 
and set compiler flags so that you can #ifdef in places.

If there are lots of files that are only applicable in the full version, 
then you can right-click on them and remove them from the Lite target to make a smaller app.

Also there is [Good SO Question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549462/how-do-i-manage-building-a-lite-vs-paid-version-of-an-iphone-app)